# Visual Studio Debug shows old variable name

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Premium for C++ developing and found weird problem.
I have a class with some members, then refactored names of two of them and Visual Debug Watch in Debug mode shows variables with wrong values with old names. In Release mode everything is OK.
Does anyone know what can cause it?

Comment: Clearly you failed to rebuild some or all of the binaries.  The typical reason is that you had another debug session open when you attempted the rebuild, so the build process could not write to the exe or pdb files.  There are many other possibilities for **why** your rebuild was not complete.  But there aren't plausible reasons other than rebuild failures for stale date in the next debug session.

Comment: I've deleted all directories that may contain build files and problem still occurs

Comment: Could it be that your refactoring failed? Can you search your code base for the old names? Are they still in use? Watch window stores the names of the variables you've added to it; what is in your Locals window?

Comment: Refactoring succeeded. This class was class Recording with fields num_samples and fs, now they was changed to numSamples and samplingRate. Problem occurs in method of this class, pointer this (in Locals windows) is said to have old named members, not new ones.